Monorepo issue with shared folder and Docker
I set up a monorepo project with 3 packages
./project1
./project2
./project3
./shared
Each project has it's own dockerfile and docker compose file
I used npm link to use the shared folder and add this in each package.json :
depedencies:{ "@my-shared/types": "file:../shared" }
and then I can import like this :
import { stuff } from '@my-shared/types';
For example if I run the command  "npm run dev" in my project1 (which is a node api) Everything is working fine ! Unless... i'm using docker. If I run the command "docker compose up" in the ./project1 folder then I get error because it can't find my shared folder.
This is my dockerfile :
FROM node:lts-slim

ENV TZ=Europe/Paris

ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3001

CMD npm run dev

And this is my docker-compose :
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - dbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - api-net
    command: mongod --quiet --logpath /dev/null 
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Paris
  
  my-api:
    build: .
    image: my-api 
    restart: always 
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    volumes: 
      - .:/app  
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - api-net
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Paris

networks:
  api-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:

I guess I just need to add the folder but I can't figure it out how.
Thank you for your help

I'd recommend deleting the my-api: { volumes: } block, so that you're actually running the code in your image and not overwriting everything with whatever happens to be on the local machine.  Once you've done that, this is the problem described in How to include files outside of Docker's build context?; you need to change the build: { context: } to the parent directory, and update the left-hand side of COPY and ADD lines.

For your apps to get the shared modules you need to include them in the volumes section of your app like so:
my-api:
    build: .
    image: my-api 
    restart: always 
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    volumes: 
      - .:/app  
      - ./yourSharedFolderPath 
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - api-net
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Paris


I think it's the wat but it doesn't work. I added ../shared and it just create a folder in my ./project1 even if I write ../../shared. it's like it doesnt want to look outside the dir. I even tried to copy the file in the dockerfile but it says he cant found the dir

I solved it,
in my docker-compose.yml in the volume section I added :

../shared:/shared

Thank you for your help
